# Emoji symbols rendering as HTML code

Tags: marketing-cloud

The email we just deployed via an user-initiated send in the Marketing Cloud had a subject line leveraging emojis (which we commonly use). Everything looked fine in test sends and in Litmus. When the we setup the email in the UI the emojis which were rendering perfectly fine turned into HTML code (&#128181 ; and &#128338 ;). Our team assumed this was just an interface issue since everything was fine in the actual email creative and through testing so we proceeded with deployment. Sure enough our emails hit inboxes with the HTML markup instead of the actual emoji symbols.

When we went back to check the UI again, the emojis which were showing as HTML before were now showing back as the emoji symbols - when we toggled off the email and back again the symbols converted to HTML again.

Clearly there is some sort of system glitch here and we were wondering if any other instances were experiencing this or if it's isolated to our account?

Comment: Were you putting in the 'emoji' as the code or were you copy/pasting the entity itself?

Comment: We were copy/pasting the entity itself - we've been using emoji's the same way in our emails for the past 2 years. This is the first time I've seen the tool do this ever.

Comment: agreed - it shouldn't do that.  To verify, you are doing the interaction "User Initiated Send' and not just a guided send, right?  Has anything changed in the way you place the emoji (e.g. insert via an API call or via AMPscript, store in a Data Extension, etc) as the character may get reformatted, etc. if moved this way.

Comment: Yes, we were doing this via a 'User Initiated Send' and nothing changed in our process. It's really weird and I think it's just an unexplainable bug in the back-end system and unfortunately affected our live deployment.

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to this issue? @kat

Comment: A year and a half later and this issue still exists....